# Replace values in file with object properties

Tags: c#, .net, xml, code-generation, t4

I am going to have template files that I will be using to generate XML files . Templates have server code blocks with object and property for example

```
<firstname><%=User.FirstName%></firstname>
<# include address.tpl pass=User> address.tpl will have address node
```

Is there any way to do that ?   I already used T4 Templates but its not flexible as I need to include multiple nested templates and also pass objects to it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand, however it looks like those files are just legitimate XML files, therefore you can create your own XML crawler to do that. If that's not what you are looking for please elaborate the question.

Here is some info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx